# What's the missing sentence to this rice-planting song："花花铺盖几朵云，刚刚盖到两个人，[.......]"?

Tags: songs

[In this video](https://youtu.be/PtEMCgVp-nQ?t=164) the speaker mentions a rice-planting song that goes like this:

> 花花铺盖几朵云哦
>   刚刚盖到两个人咯

But he mentions that there's another sentence on the end that he won't mention because he's on TV.

[This article](http://www.szhaiyun.com/biyoujingdian/d3820244.htm) also basically sites the video exactly:

> 不只是当年陕北人民才爱这个调调。你看四川评书人李伯清爷爷说的：“花花铺盖几朵云，刚刚盖到两个人……”民歌经常是火辣直接的，天南地北都有这样的东西。

But again the last sentence is left off.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason the first one is hard to find is because 朵 is also written 朶.

---

Tang Huaxian's (唐华先) book《寒冬》Chapter 8《[汤龙轩作伥抓壮丁 地下党哄营解危难](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:uvbnJUghwBgJ:www.cangqiongkanshu.com/home-project-chap-id-175-book_id-53.html%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=tw)》mentions:

> 这日夜雨初歇，清早起来，天气微凉，东边的山顶燃起桔红色的彩霞，正是挎田栽秧的天时，也是炎热似火的日子。趁着早晨凉快，钟嘴埫一湾一湾的水田里，刚刚开亮口就敲响了栽秧锣鼓。两名歌师，一个打鼓，一个敲锣，站在田埂上一人一段地唱：
>
> 花花铺盖几朶云哟，
>   刚刚盖到两个人呀。
>   大汗淋淋的老公一脚蹬床下噻，
>   光屁股婆娘心痛一槽捡不赢哪。
>
> 一阵叮叮噹噹的过门锣鼓之后，另一位歌师接唱：
>
> 二十岁的姑娘娶进门哟，
>   十二岁的小老公还未长成人呀。
>   半夜找婆娘要水喝噻，
>   天亮起来铺盖尿得水淋淋哪。

---

[This forum](https://dq.tieba.com/p/2126302344) also mentions a rendition on this:

> 一床铺盖四朵云
>   刚刚盖到两个人
>   今年两口子
>   明年三个人

---

I don't know which one 李伯清 was talking of, but there you go.